# read JSON result as array of dictionary

Tags: json, swift, xcode, swift4, alamofire

how to parse following JSON result

```
{
        "AddedByName": "jhon",
        "ApproveAction": 0,
        "ApproveActionName": "",
        "photos": null,
        "Status": 0,

    },
    {
        "AddedByName": "mike",
        "ApproveAction": 0,
        "ApproveActionName": "",
        "photos": null,
        "Status": 0,
    },
    {
        "AddedByName": "someone",
        "ApproveAction": 0,
        "ApproveActionName": "",
        "photos": [
            {
                "Id": 53,
                "Serial": 1,
                "Url": "0afe88a3-76e1-4bac-a392-173040936300.jpg"
            }
        ],
        "Status": 0,
    }
```

how can i reach the "photos" array ?

I already declare local array of dictionary to hold the whole responses as following

```
    var myLocalArray = [[String:Any]]()
```

and fill it from the JSON response like this

```
                if let Json = response.result.value as? [String:Any] {

                if let ActionData = Json["ActionData"] as? [[String:Any]] {

                    self. myLocalArray = ActionData

                }
            }
```

and it works

but i couldn't reach the "photos" array please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**@swiftIos** provided the answer with Decodable which is absolutely a better way to handle the situation.

But with your current you can access the `photos` from `self.myLocalArray`:

```
if let jsonData = response.result.value as? [String: Any] {
    if let actionData = jsonData["ActionData"] as? [[String:Any]] {
        self.myLocalArray = actionData
    }
}
```

Now you have array for `actionData`, so access the photos by extracting the `actionData` for particular index as `self.myLocalArray[0]`. In whole:

```
let index = 0
if self.myLocalArray.count > index {
    if let photoArrayIndex0 = self.myLocalArray[index]["photos"] as? [[String: Any]] {
        print(photoArrayIndex0)
    }
}
```

Comment: if let imgeArray = myLocalArray[indexPath.row]["Photos"] as? [[String:Any]] {
         let imgUrl = imgeArray[indexPath.row]["Url"] as! String
            }
            but gives me following error 
            Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range

Comment: You are trying to access index more than presented element in array. Updated my answer for this check as well.

Answer (score 1):

I will give you smart solution than can be useful at each you try to transform you Json to useful data model and make it easier to manipulate .
Using the power of Decodable .
This Model will help you to capture you Json

```
struct User: Decodable {
    var AddedByName: String
    var ApproveAction: Int
    var ApproveActionName: String
    var photos: [Photo]?
    var Status: Int

    struct Photo: Decodable {
        var Id: Int
        var Serial: Int
        var Url: String
    }
}
```

And now will be just one line to get your Json to structure data:

```
let responseData = try JSONDecoder().decode([User].self, from: jsonD)
```

Comment: that's great idea but means to work again from the scratch :(

Comment: i need temporary solution if that's ok

Comment: This way will help you to improve time and it's part of DRY ( Don't repeat your self)

Comment: but it's take time :(

Comment: I can understand, but just take a look at this two link how it's will make the request so much easier . this for request structure https://pastebin.com/suzLrzNq . and this link for how you can make a request https://pastebin.com/huBH1HDR